# Remove a range of items from a Vec

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec` in Rust with 100 items, and I need to remove every item whose index is between 10 and 30. One way to do this would be removing each element individually like so:

```
for i in 10..30 {
    vec.remove(i);
}
```

But this causes a memcpy for each removed item, because the rest of the Vec has to be shifted left every time an element is removed. How do I remove a whole range of items from a Vec in one shot, in a way that only causes one memcpy?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> How do I remove a whole range of items from a Vec in one shot

Use [`Vec::drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain):

```
vec.drain(10..30); // delete elements at indexes 10, 11, ..., 28, 29
```

You can use the return value of `drain()` to iterate over the dropped elements, but if you just ignore it (i.e. immediately drop it, as shown above), then it's exactly equivalent to a range removal.